# c# winforms GDI+

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I have a bitmap that I have created by tiling the same graphic multiple times.  When the bitmap is created it colours the tiles based on specific criteria.

When the bitmap is loaded, I then want to give the user the options to change the tile colours based on further pre-defined criteria.  Would I therefore need to discard the current bitmap, generate again with the new colours and attach to the panel.  Or can I iterate through the bitmap for each tile and change the colours that way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how often the user is likely to change the tile colours. If they're not going to be doing it too often then it's probably easier to generate a new bitmap (mostly because your code seems like it's optimized for this scenario).

A better more performant possibiliy however is to use the Bitmap.LockBits/UnlockBits methods to get at the pixel data in the bitmap then manipulate the pixel data direcly. See the MSDN documentation on the Bitmap.LockBits method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx) for a sample on how to do this.

Comment: http://www.bobpowell.net/lockingbits.htm is also worth checking out if you want to use 'unsafe' code instead (it'll be a little bit faster).

Comment: Yes, there are ways to improve the performance of a pixel-by-pixel operation on a bitmap. But there's no reason to assume that's going to be faster than simply regenerating the bitmap.

Comment: I would say that depends on how much memory pressure the GC is under and how much of the image needs to change. If only a couple of locations in the image need to change then you're probably better to change the pixel data; if the change alters most of the image content then it's likely that the regeneration of the bitmap is faster.

Comment: thanks.  And yes, it will be the whole image that needs to change, so I will redraw as it won't requiring updating a great number of times.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the only way you can go through the bitmap and change colors is to do it pixel by pixel, so I think your best shot is to generate the bitmap from scratch when the user selects new colors.

Comment: This is correct. A bitmap is a spatially-mapped array of pixels. It doesn't have any concept of the "tiles" you added to the image. Recolor the pixels in a single tile, then re-create your multi-tiled graphic again. Make sure you dispose of the previous bitmap when you no longer need it.